No GIT Icon in VSCode (where I need to see it)
In Explorer there will be Git icons - U, A, a dot, etc. - when a change has occurred and needs to be pushed. Howver, once this is done, there is no Git icon indicating there is a repo located in a folder. Only when I drill down through each folder will I find the .git folder and know for certain the parent folder contains a repo.

VSCode: 1.88.1
Start git-bash: 1.2.1
vscode-icons: 12.7.0
Git History: 0.6.20

Is this standard behvaior?
I didn't try anything. I thought having installed Start git-bash and vscode-icons would have been the only requirement.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes, this is standard behaviour. Git/SCM diff decorations in VS Code only display for changes from the current HEAD. If you stage all changes and then commit them, the head moves to the new commit and there will be no changes (until you make some new changes) from the (new) current HEAD.
If you just want an indication that your workspace folder is / has SCM repositories, you can use the window.title setting (see ${activeRepositoryName} and
${activeRepositoryBranchName}), or just focus the Source Control View, which will list repositories detected in the workspace folder.
